# Regex url identify / substitute

Tags: regex, url

I have several url's need to identify, so I can identify url match for redirect.

The url layout is of form
`/WebRoot/dir/dir/123454321/598A/CC67/DEC2/EDF8/D445/C0A8/29BF/ABBB/image.jpg`

I want to identify this url with regex so I can identify
`/WebRoot/dir/dir/123454321/*/image.jpg`

The `/598A/CC67/DEC2/EDF8/D445/C0A8/29BF/ABBB/` part is always same length, and differs from characters within each 4-digit section.

Comment: So: you input sample is `/WebRoot/dir/dir/123454321/598A/CC67/DEC2/EDF8/D445/C0A8/29BF/ABBB/image.jpg`. What is the corresponding expected output you should obtain? `/598A/CC67/DEC2/EDF8/D445/C0A8/29BF/ABBB/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the corresponding expected output for input `/WebRoot/dir/dir/123454321/598A/CC67/DEC2/EDF8/D445/C0A8/29BF/ABBB/image.jpg` should be `/598A/CC67/DEC2/EDF8/D445/C0A8/29BF/ABBB`, you can use the regexp `/\/WebRoot\/dir\/dir\/123454321((\/[A-Z0-9]{4}){8})\/image[.]jpg/` and obtain the expected output as the first captured group.

This is a running example (in JavaScript).

```js
const input = "/WebRoot/dir/dir/123454321/598A/CC67/DEC2/EDF8/D445/C0A8/29BF/ABBB/image.jpg"
const regex = /\/WebRoot\/dir\/dir\/123454321((\/[A-Z0-9]{4}){8})\/image[.]jpg/
const result = input.replace(regex, "$1")
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, was messing up with the brackets section. Your answer helped me solve it!